# Counting of values scattered in multiple columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have trying to get the count of repetitive values in multiple columns in Power BI.
I tried below solutions but they are all giving me result only from first column that is being mentioned in a query

Sample :

Count Yes =

IF ( Table1[Dim1] = “Yes”, 1, 0 )

```
+ IF ( Table1[Dim2] = “Yes”, 1, 0 ) 

+ IF ( Table1[Dim3] = “Yes”, 1, 0 ) 

+ IF ( Table1[Dim4] = “Yes”, 1, 0 )
```

Sample : SUMX (

```
UNION ( 

    SELECTCOLUMNS ( ‘Table1’, “ContainsYes”, ‘Table1′[Dim1] ), 

    SELECTCOLUMNS ( ‘Table1’, “ContainsYes”, ‘Table1′[Dim2] ), 

    SELECTCOLUMNS ( ‘Table1’, “Containsyes”, ‘Table1′[Dim3] ), 

    SELECTCOLUMNS ( ‘Table1’, “ContainsYes”, ‘Table1′[Dim4] ) 

), 

IF ( [ContainsYes] = “Yes”, 1, 0 )
```

)

Below is a data from which We want to get count of distinct product

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOU0d.png)

I tried solutions mentioned above

Comment: What does your data mean? Prepaid what? What Product? If this is a crosstab, what's the intersection of the two mean?
I'm asking, because you have to unpivot this so that you have may 3 columns. Then you might be able to summarize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a measure to achieve this

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(UNION ( 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Data, "Final", Data[Product.1] ), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Data, "Final", Data[Product.2] ), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Data, "Final", Data[Product.3] ), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Data, "Final", Data[Product.4] ), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Data, "Final", Data[Product.5] ), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Data, "Final", Data[Product.6] )
)))
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could design the table correctly and then the measure is really simple:
COUNTROWS('Data')

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but the source of your problems (because there will be more) is that your design is less than ideal.